# Align image with text in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, material-design, angular-material

I have the following HTML bit, for some reason the text is displayed below the image and not next to it

Here's how it looks like:

```css
.fbstats {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.fbstats .likeimg {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
          <div class="card-action" layout="row">
            <div class="fbstats" layout="column" layout-align="right start" flex="50">
              <img class="likeimg" src="img/like.png" /> 126
            </div>
            <div layout="column" flex="50" layout-align="left end">
              <a href="#">צפה בפוסט</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

End result looks like this:

[image]

I tried playing around with `vertical-align` and with `display: inline-flex`, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divs have a block display by default, causing them to go to the bottom of the preceding one. Check this:

```
.card-action > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display:flex` to container like this :

```css
.card-action {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.fbstats {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.fbstats .likeimg {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-action" layout="row">
  <div class="fbstats" layout="column" layout-align="right start" flex="50">
    <img class="likeimg" src="img/like.png" /> 126
  </div>
  <div layout="column" flex="50" layout-align="left end">
    <a href="#">צפה בפוסט</a>
  </div>
</div>
```